# Screen content moves prior to navigation in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I have a main compose with a scaffold, top app bar, FAB, navigation bar. Then I have a couple of composable screens I can navigate to and the navigation animation is working fine, which means the default fade in, fade out of Accompanist Navigation Animation.

Then I have another screen, let's call it B, which has its own scaffold and top app bar.
Whenever I navigate to that screen B, the content of the main screen weirdly jump up quickly before fading out. And when I come back, the content of screen B moves down quickly before fading out.

Is there a way to force the content to stay in place?
I guess it as to do with navigating from a scaffold to another one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using Accompanist, but its navigation animation APIs have been copied to `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0`. This bug remained.
There is a recent [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295536728) on issuetracker, where I may have found the problem.

Make sure that your screens take the entire size of the parent, e.g. `Modifier.fillMaxSize()`. This is because guys at Google didn't override the default `SizeTransform` argument in `ContentTransform`'s primary constructor, which goes like this:

```kotlin
fun SizeTransform(
    clip: Boolean = true,
    sizeAnimationSpec: (initialSize: IntSize, targetSize: IntSize) -> FiniteAnimationSpec<IntSize> =
        { _, _ ->
            spring(
                stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow,
                visibilityThreshold = IntSize.VisibilityThreshold
            )
        }
): SizeTransform = SizeTransformImpl(clip, sizeAnimationSpec)
```

So there you have your jumping - it's because your screen content could be changing in size. You didn't provide any code, so it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have come upon this situation or something similar, and I suspect there is something about having Scaffold inside NavHost; my first thought is to have it the other way around, so NavHost inside Scaffold, as per the official docs.